# Allow .php One directory htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This is what I have for removing .php using the htaccess. My issue is that I'm testing out wordpess within a directory -  1_wordpress  - I believe this setting is not allowing me to sign in after installation. I've had this issue before when doing custom non wordpress building. The issue I finally found out tobe was I was using .php within the action of a form. Removing the .php worked as the site no longer used .php. Any tips on adjusting this is much appreciated.

```
# Begin remove .php from urls
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
# End remove .php from urls
```

Comment: `htaccess` files work on a per-directory basis. You could add an additional `htaccess` file to the relevant folder.

Comment: Hi Lix . Can something like this be reversed? So does this mean this isnt the issue?

Comment: How do you mean reversed? Also, don't forget to use [comment replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) otherwise users will not know you have responded to them.

Comment: Is there an opposite to returning to .php or is it by default something that is not occurring within the wordpress directory? @Lix

Comment: I'm not too familiar with wordpress at all.. I do have some experience with htaccess files... I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: What would be the opposite of what I'm doing above is I guess what I'm saying.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52473/discussion-between-user3135730-and-lix)